# bad break in bounty banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, layout

The bounty banner looks bad. I’d be surprised if it’s always looked like this and I never noticed, so I suspect something was broken. Here’s a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of badly broken bounty banner]

There are two related problems with this. (I chose the one that made for a better alliteration for the title.)

- The space between “bounty.” and the linked user name is missing. It looks as if someone called “bounty.PkT” wants to draw attention to the question.
- The line break before “bounty” is unnecessary, and indeed if I modify the HTML to include the missing space, the break occurs after the period as it should. (This is not just for one arbitrary browser window width; I get this layout of the banner (in both Firefox and Safari) for any window width above roughly $1265$ pixels.)

Comment: FYI, the first problem was reported several days ago in the network Meta post [Missing space in bounty notice on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/562482). Also, the first comment there by Cody Gray links to the meta Stack Overflow post [The case of the missing space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423569/11726740), which deals with the similar problem occurring with migration notices, and with this post having been marked as "status-review".

Comment: A missing space, eh? So lacking literal leaves layout lover livid?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: https://youtu.be/Vud0sD7X4jA?t=34

Comment: This was fixed, per the MSE post linked above.